# java IOException: Write end dead during a hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a map-only hadoop job, that throws several IO exceptions during it's work:

1) java.io.IOException: Write end dead

2) java.io.IOException: Pipe closed

It manages to finish it's work, but there exceptions make me worry. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Practically the same job is working daily on another dataset which is 20 times smaller, and no exceptions are thrown. Jobs are run by Google dataproc.

The config file I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-D mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true \
-D mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
-D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
-D mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=1500000000 \
-D mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent=1 \
-D mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2 \
-D mapreduce.task.timeout=900000 \
-D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 \
-file mymapper.py \
-input gs://input_folder/* \
-output gs://output_folder/$1 \
-mapper mymapper.py \
-reducer org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer \
-inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineTextInputFormat
```

Here is an error log:

```
17/03/15 09:53:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: 
job_1489571529338_0001
17/03/15 09:53:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1489571529338_0001 running in uber mode : false
17/03/15 09:53:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/03/15 09:56:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 1% reduce 0%
17/03/15 10:00:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1489571529338_0001_m_000744_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Write end dead
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:432)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.write(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:256)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:58)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:78)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:101)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:61)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:174)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopOutputStream.close(GoogleHadoopOutputStream.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.close(CompressorStream.java:109)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter.close(TextOutputFormat.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$DirectMapOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Write end dead
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:432)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:287)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.close(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:68)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.close(Channels.java:178)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Write end dead
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:310)
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
        at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:181)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setContentAndHeadersOnCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:629)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:409)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:358)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.io.IOException: Write end dead]

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

17/03/15 10:01:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 2% reduce 0%
17/03/15 10:02:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1489571529338_0001_m_001089_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.checkStateForReceive(PipedInputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:226)
    at java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:149)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.write(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:259)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:58)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:78)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:101)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:61)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:174)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopOutputStream.close(GoogleHadoopOutputStream.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.close(CompressorStream.java:109)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter.close(TextOutputFormat.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$DirectMapOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Write end dead
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:432)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:287)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.close(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:68)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.close(Channels.java:178)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Write end dead
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:310)
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
        at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:181)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setContentAndHeadersOnCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:629)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:409)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:358)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

17/03/15 10:03:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1489571529338_0001_m_001217_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.checkStateForReceive(PipedInputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:226)
    at java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:149)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.write(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:259)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:58)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Channels.java:78)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Channels.java:101)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:61)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:174)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopOutputStream.close(GoogleHadoopOutputStream.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.close(CompressorStream.java:109)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter.close(TextOutputFormat.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$DirectMapOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Write end dead
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:432)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:287)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.close(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:68)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.close(Channels.java:178)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Write end dead
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:310)
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
        at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:181)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setContentAndHeadersOnCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:629)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:409)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:358)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

17/03/15 10:04:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 3% reduce 0%
17/03/15 10:08:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 4% reduce 0%
17/03/15 10:12:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 5% reduce 0%
```

UPD.

Now it comes with Backend Error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWrit
eChannel.java:432)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:287)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.close(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloud
Storage.java:68)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.close(Channels.java:178)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopOutputStream.close(GoogleHadoopOutputStream.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.close(CompressorStream.java:109)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter.close(TextOutputFormat.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$DirectMapOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually `Write end dead` means a writer thread failed to `close()` the output stream before exiting, but if it's happening in something in the underlying framework rather than any kind of manually created write channel, it's likely the result of some transient failure which caused a single task to fail for other reasons, and then the `Write end dead` message is just another symptom of the failure.

In your case, the `410 Gone` error is a known transient failure mode of GCS which is not recoverable in the same stream (recoverable errors are automatically retried silently under the hood). But that's just a single failed task, and Hadoop ensures that failed tasks will get retried end-to-end for the job, and only if the same task fails too many times will the overall job fail.

So in general, it means as long as your overall job completes successfully, then all your data was processed correctly; single-task failures can just be treated as warnings.

Comment: Well, from a certain moment my jobs fail to finish successfully due to `410` error, so I'm stuck with unprocessed data.
Is `Write and dead` caused by any of my scripts or Hadoop configs, or it is just a backend error? 
Is there anything I can do to find a workaround from this situation? Anything to avoid `410` error or `Write and dead` warning?

Comment: So the jobs are fully failing? I thought you said "It manages to finish it's work, but there exceptions make me worry"; if the job finishes, then the exceptions just mean that individual tasks had to be retried, but there isn't any unprocessed data in the end.